# android wear - eclipse : not recognizing support library

Tags: android, eclipse, wear-os

Im trying to develop with the new Wear sdk.

I have downloaded everyting needed including support libraries and set up android wear to go. 
the problem I have is that the project cant find the wearable libararies.

code error lines example:

```
WatchActivity cannot be resolved to a type
```

and

```
The import android.support.wearable cannot be resolved
```

Thank you, Yakir.

Comment: Please tell if my solution below was helpful. If not please tell what is the current status of your issue:)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've gone through the same issues using Eclipse and the answer to my problem was following link that I've found: 
http://blog.benjamin-cabe.com/2014/07/04/how-to-setup-eclipse-for-android-wear-development

### WatchActivity:

just don't use `WatchActivity` - use standard Activity instead.

### The import android.support.wearable cannot be resolved:

**First step** is to make sure that you have installed a `Google Repository` Extra in your SDK Manager. It should be located somewhere below the `Android Support Repository`
[image]


**After downloading the `Google Repository`:**
In Android Studio you just need to add a dependency for wearable-support lib like done here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html#UiLibrary.
But if you want to use any class from `android.support.wearable` package from Eclipse it is a little bit tricky.
Wearable package is not included in standard android-support library - you need to use wearable UI support lib located in google repository: `com.google.android.support:wearable`
Unlike the standard android-support libs, this one is not provided as a `.jar` file or project code that you can import right to your workspace, but it's in `.aar` format (like `jar` but also including `res`).

Please find this file here, relative to your sdk folder: 
`./extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/support/wearable/1.0.0/wearable-1.0.0.aar`

1. Unzip `wearable-1.0.0.aar` file somwehere to your workspace (you can see it looks almost like a standard android project)
2. Move `classes.jar` to `/libs/classes.jar`
3. Now you have to create new project from these files, with package name defined as `android.support.wearable`
4. Compile it with API 20 and select "Is Library" in project properties
5. Add reference to this library project from your project

I recomment you to take a look at this blog post. There is everything explained well step-by-step. If you will have any project feel free to ask in comment here.

Comment: My configurations - Eclipse Kepler - ADT Upto-date (checked by trying offline installation as well as online update service for eclipse) but still no luck in finding "wearable" folder/libs in the support folder (Also the path for the same you specified here, is different in windows). Any idea?

Comment: Im using windows and this path was from windows. What is your path to wearable-1.0.0.aar in google's m2repository?

Comment: Path: .\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support & in that i am not able to find "wearable" folder which is expected & there is no update available in my SDKManager as well as Eclipse.

Comment: The wearable support lib is not a part of Android Support Lib and it is not located in /extras/android but in /extras/google. Have you downloaded a "Google Repository" from SDK Manager? (It should be somewhere below the "Android Support Repository" in "Extras" section of your SDK Manager)

Comment: Ahhaa... Installed "Google Repository" & It works. Thank You.

Comment: No problem. I will add it to my answer to highlight this step, because many people can be confused with the "Google repository" instead of "Android Support Repository".

Answer (score 0):

You can disregard the `WatchActivity` compile error, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24463815/592153.

If you can't find `android.support.wearable`, make sure you've followed step 4. in this guide: http://developer.android.com/preview/google-play-services-wear.html

Comment: Under `~/.android/extras`, do you see these file 
./extras/google/google_play_services/docs/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable
./extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wearable
./extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wearable/5.0.77
./extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/support/wearable
./extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/support/wearable/1.0.0


If not, try deleting the `/extras/google` folder and downloading it again from the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the wearable library inside Google Repository folder. On how to extract and use it, you can refer to https://medium.com/@tangtungai/how-to-develop-and-package-android-wear-app-using-eclipse-ef1b34126a5d

Hope this help