# Error : WatchActivity cannot be resolved to a type,Why i'm getting this?

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-adt, android-sdk-tools

Well i have update my Android Sdk to 23 & even Eclips ADT plugin to the latest version.

why i'm getting the error in import library of WatchActivity . And i have already fixed this issue "[Update eclipse with Android Development tools 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23)".

- When i create a new android project with "Blank Activity" my Src & Layout folder is empty.
- When i create a new android project with "Blank Wear Activity" it will create scr folder with Activity file bit contains an error `WatchActivity cannot be resolved to a type`

[image]

[image]

Comment: @chrisf I don't think it is a duplicate to the question you have pointed to

Comment: @ChrisF my question over here is, why i'm getting the error in import library of WatchActivity not about the Error you mention as duplicate "Update eclipse with Android Development tools 23",Already i was able to fix that issue.

Comment: @ChrisF Can you say me that , why i'm getting the this error "WatchActivity cannot be resolved to a type" And the mark my question as duplicate.

Comment: please edit the question to show why it's not a duplicate. Then it will be placed on the reopen review queue where it can be assessed by other users

Comment: @Chrisf i have edited my question,pls go through it.

Comment: After updating the Android SDK tool to 23.0.1,They have removed the "Blank wear Activity,Map Activity ..etc"
And the empty Src & Layout folder issue
Check out this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @ChrisF:This is not a duplicate question!

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is just a faulty template, extending e.g. `InsetActivity` instead of the non-existing `WatchActivity` works fine. There's also other issues with the template, e.g. inflating the layout in `onCreate` instead of in `onReadyForContent`.
Please see my sample project at https://github.com/sveinungkb/wear-test for a working template.