# Error "No resource identifier found for attribute 'rectLayout'"

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I was trying to create a new project for android wear in eclipse , but there is a problem in main layout i don't now how i can solve it , this is my main layout:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/watch_view_stub"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:rectLayout="@layout/rect"
    app:roundLayout="@layout/round"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">
</android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub>
```

it is give me this error :

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'rectLayout' in package 
     'com.example.wear'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundLayout' in package 
     'com.example.wear'
```

my project have two layouts "rect.xml" and "round.xml" and it is compile with 4.4W and target is 4.4W and also i have a copy of classes.jar in libs folder .

Comment: I don't think there is an attribute called rectLayout for `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you've posted is fine. The problem here is that you have a copy of `classes.jar` in your `/libs` folder, but this is not a right way to properly use **wearable-support-lib**. This **wearable-support-lib** contains some resources that cannot be packaged inside a `.jar` file, so you need to import it as a "**Library project**" and attach it to your project just like other external libraries.

You need to go back to the `wearable-1.0.0.aar` file, located in relation to your sdk folder: 
`./extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/support/wearable/1.0.0/wearable-1.0.0.aar`

1. Unzip the whole `wearable-1.0.0.aar` file somwehere to your workspace. You will see that it looks almost like a standard android project.
2. Move `classes.jar` to `/libs/classes.jar` - inside this project, not to your own project.
3. Now you have to create new project from these files, with package name defined `android.support.wearable`.
4. Compile it with API 20 and check "Is Library" in project properties in **Android** tab.
5. Add reference to this library project from your project.

You can see more details about using **wearable-support-lib** in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24754539/3827276) and in [this great blog post](http://blog.benjamin-cabe.com/2014/07/04/how-to-setup-eclipse-for-android-wear-development) (by Benjamin Cabé).

Answer (score 1):

I just added the following code in the dependency section in my `build.gradle` of the module:
`compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.3'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.0'`

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was changing this:
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

To:
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.mydomain.myapp"

Where com.mydomain.myapp is the package id of my app.

Presumably the res-auto functionality was not working in my project for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too sometimes, in my case i solved it by rightclicking on the AppCompat map then click on refresh, do this with your projectfolder too.